# Form in ListBox do not use ToString() to Display list item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Main Form:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("A");
            listBox1.Items.Add(new SimpleForm());
        }

    }

}
```

Form to be added to list:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class SimpleForm : Form
    {
        public SimpleForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "SimpleForm";
        }

    }

}
```

ListBox item 2 is blank instead of "SimpleForm". Any other objects use ToString() with no problems.

This is my first question so be gental. Stackoverflow has helped me so many times over the years.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Can you be more specific and provide more details?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code tested here displays "SimpleForm" for the second item

Comment: @zaggler, as steve mentioned, i cannot reproduce issue.

Comment: @zaggler if you add an object to the WinForms ListBox it should call ToString() on that object to obtain a textual representation of the object (form or not) The asker cannot get this result but in my test I get the "SimpleForm" expected output

Comment: @Steve I reproduced it, using 4.7.2 and same code as above.

Comment: There's a breaking change in newer .Net Framework versions. You have to set `FormattingEnabled = false`, otherwise the internal Add() method returns `GetItemText([new Item])`, which is of course an empty string. When the property is set to `false`, `[Item].ToString()` is returned instead.

Comment: @Jimi do you have a reference to this change? All I can find are the Docs and there the default is still false everywhere

Comment: @Steve [private int NativeAdd(object item)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListBox.cs,1581) => [ListControl.GetItemText()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,555)

Comment: Thank you very much that you understood my question, Jimi, and that you solved the problem! I need to learn how to att code to my question...